# List of roles as an argument

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to assign role to a new user, the role is called ROLE_USER in database and has an id of 3. but I dont know how to pass that value in method save(). At the bottom, I throw the most important classes and save method.

User model class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")})
    private List<Role> roles;

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password, List<Role> roles) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.roles = roles;
    }
Getters and setters ...
```

Role model class

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="roles")
    private List<Role> users;
}
```

UserRegistrationDto class

```
 public class UserRegistrationDto {
 
     private String firstName;
     private String lastName;
     private String email;
     private String password;
     private List<Role> roles;
 }
```

method for save in UserService class

```
public User save(UserRegistrationDto registrationDto) {

    User user = new User(registrationDto.getFirstName(),
            registrationDto.getLastName(), 
            registrationDto.getEmail(),
            passwordEncoder.encode(registrationDto.getPassword()), 
            ROLE ???);

    return userRepository.save(user);
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown the `Role` class.

Comment: added @tgdavies

Comment: It seems odd that `Role` contains a `List<Role>` -- and that it's named `users`.

Comment: true i changed it but still idk how to assign role for new user.